# Unable to apply zclip object to my element ids that were created after onLoad()?

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

So I am trying to get zclip working with my site. Basically, after the page loads, i just an ".get()" function to create my list. for each table row, i have a table data with a button  that i want it to copy data from another table data. The problem is, i am reading that the zclip can only be applied to code that was created in "onLoad". I need to be able to get this working on after pageLoad. my list is dynamic so things change. and it takes time to load my table, so i did it this way.

Here is a piece of how my code works

```
$(document).ready(function() 
   // get this after everything loads //
   $.get(url, function(data) {
       $('#list-information').html(data); // data is an html string echoed by php ajax call
       // this button is created in the above call the above is called
        $('a#test-button').zclip({
          path:'http://mytest.com/files/ZeroClipboard.swf',
          copy: function() {return 'hellomee'}
        });
   });

});
```

the 'test-button' never gets "glued" with the swf. but when i do this outside of the .get, if i put the button on the actual html page where it can be created on initial load and not in ".get()" it works fine. Any Help would be great thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be a little late, but this should fix your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#test-button').zclip({
       path:'http://mytest.com/files/ZeroClipboard.swf',
       copy: function() {return 'hellomee'}
    }).zclip('hide').addClass('disabled'); //in your css, add a.disabled { color: #eee; }
    $.get(url, function(data) {
       $('#list-information').html(data);
       $('a#test-button').removeClass('disabled').zclip('show');
    });
});
```

As you can see, this instantiates zclip on the page load, then disables it, and then re-enables it only after the $.get receives the necessary data.